# Synchronizing items in RadioButtonList between Design and Source views

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist

After editing the list of hardcoded items in a **RadioButtonList** on a **ASP.NET** page via the **Design** view, I find that the HTML source for the RadioButtonList still does not update to the latest list of items i.e items are still the ones before the changes.

Is there a way to synchronize what appears in the Design view and the actual HTML source? Or do I have to delete the RadioButtonList and recreate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally got it. I double-clicked the RadioButtonList in the **Design View** to add an event handler for **SelectedIndexChanged** and the items were refreshed to the latest version.

I then undid the addition of the event handler in the codebehind and deleted the **onselectedindexchanged** event for the RadioButtonList in the **Source View**.